# Delay() isn't working on focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cl").on("click", function() {
    $(".inpt").delay(5000).focus();
  });
});
```

```css
.cl {
  background: #009;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inpt">
<div class="cl">click me</div>
```

Problem I have with the above code is that the `delay()` is not working on the `focus()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states that `delay` only works for animations *(unless you set up a queue)*, you probably just want a setTimeout instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cl").on("click", function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".inpt").focus();
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

For completeness, using `delay` with a queue

```
$('.inpt').delay(5000).queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).focus(); 
    next(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try an alternative to achieve this,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".cl").on("click", function () {
   setTimeout(function(){
   $(".inpt").focus();
   },5000);
  });
});
```

```css
.cl {
  background:#009;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inpt">
<div class="cl">click me</div>
```

**The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.**

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it did help :)